# How to assign an element of an tensor in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, variable-assignment

I want to understand the error message of the following code

```
M = K.eye(2)
K.assign(M[0,1],1.0)
```

The message I got is "Tried to convert 'input' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported."

Comment: which tf or keras version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign an element of a variable in tensorflow. Here is an example. (I didn't find K.assign this operation in my installed tensorflow version, btw)

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.backend as K

M = tf.Variable(K.eye(2), tf.float32)
assign_op = tf.assign(M[0,1], 1.0)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  print(sess.run(M))
  sess.run(assign_op)
  print(sess.run(M))

#[[1. 0.]
# [0. 1.]]

#[[1. 1.]
# [0. 1.]]
```